# Is there any advantage of using non-fixed integers (int, long) instead of fixed-size ones (int64_t, int32_t)?

Tags: c++, portability

Maybe performance? I feel that using non-fixed integers just makes programs more complicated and prone to fail when porting to another architecture.

Comment: I find that the exact size very rarely matters in my code -- in those cases, using fixed-size integers just adds cruft and reduces portability. What are you doing that requires you to know the bit size?

Comment: I think it comes down to the assumptions that you want to make.  Do you want to assume that a particular value will always have an exact number of bits on any architecture?  If so, a fixed-size integer may be the right choice.  If not, then you may want to just use a type that guarantees a certain minimum number of bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::intN_t` are provided [only if the implementation can directly support them](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). So porting code that uses them can fail.

I would prefer `std::intfastN_t` for general use because they have less restrictions and should be as fast or faster as `int`.

Also, most C++ code uses `int` everywhere so you might run into promotion weirdness when passing a `std::int32_t` into a function accepting an `int`, especially if `sizeof(int)` is only 16 bits.

Comment: Does uint_fast8_t behave like uint8_t, eg. 255 + 1 = 0?

Comment: @lamefun No. It can hold at least 255, possibly more. Use `uint8_t` if you need guaranteed size (which is rare for most uses).

Answer (score 0):

Many APIs accept or return values of non-fixed types. For example, file descriptors are of type `int`, file offsets or sizes are of type `off_t` and `strtol()` returns a `long`. Blindly converting such values from or to fixed-size types is likely to cause overflow on some machine.

Answer (score 0):

The guaranteed-width types (`intN_t`) are just typedefs for the appropriate 'standard' integer types. If a platform does not have an appropriate type (for example, it uses 36-bit integers), then it can't and mustn't provide the guaranteed-width typedefs.
This means that performance can hardly be an argument.

The general guideline for maximum portability (in this regard) is to use the 'standard' integer types by default and the guaranteed-width types only if your algorithm demands an exact number of bits.
The 'standard' integer types should be assumed to be only as wide as guaranteed by the relevant standards (If you only look at the C++ standard, that would be: 8-bits `char`, 16-bits `int`, 32-bits `long` and, if your compiler supports it, 64-bits `long long`).

Answer (score 0):

If you have data where the size of your type is critical for it's functionality, then you should use types with defined sizes. However, for example a piece of code that is well within [what you can reasonably expect] int range (say for example 1 ... 1000 loop counter), there is no reason to use int_32t just because you want to define that your variable. It will work just fine with a 16, 32, 64, 36, 18 or 49 bit integer, all the same. So let the compiler pick the size that is best.

There is a possibility that the compiler generates worse code for fixed size integers that aren't "best choice" for the architecture.

Obviously, any data that is presented over a network or in a file needs to have fixed size. Likewise, if you have interfaces that require binary compatibility across the interface boundary, then using defined size types is very useful to avoid the size becomming a problem.